# Redis-objects to count the number of Model instances by a column on my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-objects

I'm trying to understand how to use the Redis-Objects gem.

My goal is to Count the number of `Purchase` model instances by `customer_id`. For example, a customer loads a page and I would like to see the number of purchases by that Customer. To be clear the Purchase model has a `customer_id` column. Because of the volume of hits, I would like to use redis to relieve pressure on my server.

Does one use [set](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects#sets) to accomplish this task? How does one use the [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects) gem to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when working with Redis, it is best to model your data according to your access patterns. In other words, de-normalize your data.

Here is what I would do :

1. `Customer` and `Purchase` objects are stored in a Hash.
2. Customer hash should have a field total_purchases
3. Every time a customer purchases something, use [HINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby) to increment the total_purchases field
4. On page load, simply read the value of total_purchases